# CoreGraphics drawing results to CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, core-graphics

I'm getting tons of `CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.` errors from this code. It is executed within a SKScene. Basically I'm getting user's drawing on screen as a SKShapeNode. Then I'm populating that drawing's path with circles by Core Graphics. However the code runs slow and gives me tons of errors. I'm sort of new to Swift. Can you help me with what's going on? How can I speed this up? How can I give CoreGraphics proper context?

```
                    let boundingBox = createdShape.frame
                    for j in stride(from: Int(boundingBox.minX), to: Int(boundingBox.maxX), by: 10) {
                        for i in stride(from: Int(boundingBox.minY), to: Int(boundingBox.maxY), by: 10) {
                        //for i in 0..<10 {
                            counter += 1
                            //let originalPoint = CGPoint(x: ((boundingBox.maxX - boundingBox.minX)/2)+boundingBox.minX, y: (boundingBox.maxY-CGFloat(i*10)))
                            //let originalPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(j), y: (boundingBox.maxY-CGFloat(i*10)))
                            let originalPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(j), y: (CGFloat(i)))
                            let point:CGPoint = self.view!.convert(originalPoint, from: self)

                            if (createdShape.path?.contains(createdShape.convert(originalPoint, from: self)))! {
                                let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: point, radius: CGFloat(5), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
                                circlePath.fill()

                                let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                                shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

                                shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red:  180/255, green: 180/255, blue: 180/255, alpha: 0.4).cgColor
                                shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red:  180/255, green: 180/255, blue: 180/255, alpha: 0.4).cgColor
                                shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.0

                                view!.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Ok, looks like you are mixing 2 different technologies here, and you are getting yourself confused.  You do not want to be dealing with core graphics,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I believe the culprit line of code is:

```
circlePath.fill()
```

As `UIBezierPath.fill()` is a Core Graphics draw operation, it needs to be called within a Core Graphics context in order for it to know where it will actually be drawing.

This is usually done inside [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1623912-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwitho) / [`UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1623933-uigraphicsendimagecontext) where you explicitly create and end a context, or in certain UIKit methods like `UIView.drawRect()` where the context is automatically managed for you.

From the looks of it, calling `fill()` in that part of your code is being done outside of a context being present, which is why it's reporting an invalid context of 0x0.

In this particular case, it looks like you're using that `circlePath` object as the clipping mask for a `CAShapeLayer`, so it's probably not necessary to call `fill()` there.

Let me know if you need additional clarification. :)